# CSS - Issue maintaining labels and inputs on separate lines

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how I can get labels in my form to be maintained all on one line. That is if a label for a specific input happens to be longer than the rest, I would like the other labels to have additional white space underneath such that my input fields are in alignment. See picture for alignment issue.

[image]

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <label>Window Utilization Total:<span class="input-required" ng-show="logbook.util.$error.required">*</span></label>
            <input name="util" ng-model="sortie.total_window_time" empty-to-null required type="text" title="Time: e.g. 01:00, 12:30, 23:59, etc" maxlength="5"
                   placeholder="00:00" pattern="^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$"/>
            <p class="input-error" ng-show="logbook.util.$invalid && logbook.util.$touched">
                Invalid time (e.g. 12:00, 23:59, 1:30, etc).
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <label>Flight Plan:</label>
            <input ng-model="sortie.flight_plans" empty-to-null type="text" placeholder="e.g. NMZSAN_FP509"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <label>Partial Flight Plans (Lines Completed):</label>
            <input ng-model="sortie.partial_flight_plan" empty-to-null type="text" placeholder="e.g. NMZSAN_FP509, Lines 1-5"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <label>Date of Last Control:</label>
            <input ng-model="sortie.last_control_date" empty-to-null type="text" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you please show your code.

Comment: Only tables will allow you to restrict alignment in two dimensions. I'm (obviously?) talking about css-tables, and not `<table>` elements..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an all-css approach, it's going to be tricky. Someday, [grid layout](http://igalia.github.io/css-grid-layout/) will make this sort of thing easy, but [it has terrible support right now](http://caniuse.com/#search=grid).

However, you could use flex-box to help you.

I think it will work if you have two rows, one for labels and one for the inputs.

```
<style>
  div { display: flex }
  label, input { flex: 1 }
</style>
<div>
  <label for="1">Short</label>
  <label for="2">Also Short</label>
  <label for="3">So long ohmygoodness so much to say</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input id="1"/>
  <input id="2"/>
  <input id="3"/>
</div>
```

Here's [a jsfiddle to demonstrate it](http://jsfiddle.net/o7eddwxr/).

Note that flexbox support is not yet perfect, and you should add some browser-specific prefixes and be aware of its limitations. [Read more at caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). If you need support for older versions of IE, it looks like you'll have to use a javascript fallback as indicated in the other answer here.

Comment: As @thebjorn indicated, you could also use `display: table` and such to accomplish this. It will probably have similar results, come to think of it.

Comment: This is probably the best answer for this type of issue. I ended up just changing my bootstrap columns and shortening label names because, as you hinted, this gets pretty tricky, especially when my HTML has been pretty much fleshed out - there's a lot of rework reorganizing labels and inputs into separate lines. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this js code in your file, what this will do, it will equalize all the label height based on the height of biggest label as per its content/text.

Add class **label_big** to all the label elements

This works for me very well, hope it will resolve your issue.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    var highestBox = 0;
        $('.form_group .label_big').each(function(){  
                if($(this).height() > highestBox){  
                highestBox = $(this).height();  
        }
    });    
    $('.form_group .label_big').height(highestBox);

});
</script>
```

Comment: This *will* add unnecessary space even to the fields in the second line `.row`

Comment: Appreciate the help on this. As Roko mentioned this added extra spacing onto other portions of the form vs singling out the one row that needed the spacing. Thank you for your time in answering!